# Discord.js database sends same line from .txt

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot send a line from a .txt file, dm it to message author, delete that line from the .txt file, than be able to send the next line the next time the command is run. currently it is sending the same line to a user. any ideas of how to fix this?

```
const vpn = './Database files/VPN.txt';
let vpncodes = fs.readFileSync(vpn).toString();

if (command === "vpn") {
        if (message.member.roles.some(r => ["Ӿ-ACCESS!"].includes(r.name))) {
            if (!lock) {
            if (!vpncodes.length == 0) {
                let lines = vpncodes.split('\n');
                let user = message.author; //grabbing the user mention
                user.send("`here are your accounts: " + lines[0] + "`");
                message.channel.send("account info has been sent. check your dm's");
                lines.splice(0, 1);
                fs.writeFile(vpn, lines.join('\n'), function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)

                });
            } else {
                return message.reply("This item is out of stock");
            }
        } else {
            return message.reply("this database is currently locked");
        }
        } else {
            return message.reply("you dont have permissions to do this");
        }
    }
    module.exports.help = {
        name: 'code'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had to put the `let vpncodes = fs.readFileSync(vpn).toString();` inside command

Answer (score 0):

Use Read file in command block.

```
if (command === "vpn") {
        if (message.member.roles.some(r => ["Ӿ-ACCESS!"].includes(r.name))) {
            if (!lock) {
            if (!vpncodes.length == 0) {
            const vpn = './Database files/VPN.txt';
            let vpncodes = fs.readFileSync(vpn).toString();
                let lines = vpncodes.split('\n');
                let user = message.author; //grabbing the user mention
                user.send("`here are your accounts: " + lines[0] + "`");
                message.channel.send("account info has been sent. check your dm's");
                lines.splice(0, 1);
                fs.writeFile(vpn, lines.join('\n'), function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)

                });
            } else {
                return message.reply("This item is out of stock");
            }
        } else {
            return message.reply("this database is currently locked");
        }
        } else {
            return message.reply("you dont have permissions to do this");
        }
    }
    module.exports.help = {
        name: 'code'
    }
```